# Did SpaceX use TDRSS or USAF ground station to track Falcon 9 stage 2?

Tags: spacex, tdrss

Which system did spacex rely to? 
Falcon, not dragon

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. TDRSS isn't used for tracking; it's a data relay satellite.